# How to create a custom landing page dimension that displays the title of the page, not the link?

Tags: google-analytics, title, landing-page, custom-dimensions

I want to create a custom dimension called Landing Page Title. In short it's the same with the built-in Landing Page except that it displays the title of the page instead of the url.

How to create that dimension? The article [Create and edit custom dimensions and metrics - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) doesn't help much, because I don't know how to copy the built-in dimension. Yes, one can go to Behavior → Site Content → Landing Pages and add a secondary dimension of Page Title. However, there is no secondary dimension in the mobile app.

Comment: I thought page title was a built-in dimension in Google Analytics.

Comment: yes, but it's only page title. I need page title of landing pages only

Comment: If I understand correctly, and you are on UA then you can go to Behavior>Site Content> Landing Pages and add a secondary dimension of Page Title, that should show you just the landing pages.

Comment: @Tal Yes, but I want to display it in the app as well. There is no secondary dimension in the app

Comment: @Ooker I think that this is the best reference I can give you https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en/#modify_your_tracking_code Especially the section I marked in the url (modify your tracking code)